# Postgres: Why do smaller JSON documents take more disk space than a larger ones?

Tags: json, postgresql, storage, jsonb

I am testing how much storage space JSON documents, stored as JSONB in Postgres 9.6.4, would take for our application.  The tests produced odd results and I'm hoping someone on SO might have an explaination.

Below is a sample of the JSON document our application stores.  In the sample there are five sets of key/value pairs (valueA - valueE), however the real data contains 10-30 sets of key/values.

During my testing I created three tablea and each one persisted 100,000 documents.  Each table persisted a progressively larger JSON document of 10, 20 and 30 sets of key/values.

What I cannot explain is the table with the smallest JSON document took MUCH more space than the larger JSON documents.

There are no repeating keys and I've inspected the data in all tables and the entire JSON document is stored for all test scenarios.  In every test I create a simple, brand new table without any indexes and then load the JSON documents.

Here are my results:

100,000 JSON Documents with 
    10 sets of key/value pairs:  took 195mb of space
    20 sets of key/value pairs:  took  71mb of space
    30 sets of key/value pairs:  took  87mb of space

Does anyone know what would explain this?

Sample JSON Document:

```
{
    "values": {
        "valueA": {
            "created": "2017-08-29T22:22:13",
            "name": "targetA",
            "rank": 1.136,
            "valuetype": "expected"
        },
        "valueB": {
            "created": "2017-08-29T22:22:14",
            "name": "targetB",
            "rank": 0.067,
            "valuetype": "expected"
        },
        "valueC": {
            "created": "2017-08-29T22:22:15",
            "name": "targetC",
            "rank": 0.42,
            "valuetype": "expected"
        },
        "valueD": {
            "created": "2017-08-29T22:22:16",
            "name": "targetD",
            "rank": 0.986,
            "valuetype": "random"
        }
        "valueE": {
            "created": "2017-08-29T22:22:16",
            "name": "targetE",
            "rank": 0.111,
            "valuetype": "random"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Postgres compresses values larger the 2KB: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks!  You are 100% right.  I reran the tests using 'Alter column set storage plain' and the results changed drastically.

Now the results for 10, 20, 30 key/value sets are: 195mb, 391mb and 781mb.  Can you post your comment as an answer I can accept it?

**Thanks!**